# Can adm-zip read whole folder content in a zip file?

Tags: node.js, zip, adm-zip

I'm using adm-zip for reading files and extraction of zip folder. But I've another requirement to read whole folder present inside zip file and copy to another location. Is it possible?
I saw there is boolean flag to detect folder. Any idea ?